# when i write content in file it will add blank line on top of file in C. how to fix it

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{

        FILE *file;

        int size=0,len,i=0;

        char *str,str2,filename[20];

        printf("enter the filename :");
        scanf("%s",filename);

        //------------------For Write data in File------------------//
        file = fopen(filename,"w");
        //fseek(file,0L,2); 
        printf("input data:");
        while((str2=getchar())!= 27)
        {
            putc(str2,file);
        }
        fclose(file);

        //------------------For Read data in File------------------//
        file = fopen(filename,"r");
        fseek(file,0L,2);
        len = ftell(file);
        size=len;
        fseek(file,0L,0);

        str=(char *)malloc(len *sizeof(char));
        while((str2=getc(file))!= EOF)
        {
            str[i]=str2;i++;
        }
        printf("\nFile Data:-\n");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            printf("%c",str[i]);
        }
        fclose(file);
        printf("\n"); 
}
```

Comment: i understand that but, what can i do changes in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program essentially gets file name as input and then keeps scanning input data until it encounters Esc. First part of this program is important and the logic is something similar to this.

```
   char fname[20]; // Buffer to store File-Name
   scanf("%s", fname);
```

Manual for scanf says

> s      Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next
>   pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to
>   hold the input sequence and the terminating null character ('\0'),
>   which is added automatically.  The input string stops at white space
>   or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

which means everything is scanned into char buffer till new line character, which is let untouched in input buffer.

and when getchar() is sees this leftover'\n' in while loop scans this character and proceeds to writing into file.

```
while((str2=getchar())!= 27)
    {
        putc(str2,file);
    }
```

Thus

First character in the line becomes a line.

Remove unnecessary characters from input buffer

```
printf("enter the filename :");
scanf("%s%*c",filename);
```

Comment: But can u explain me in detail what actually happens ? thnx in advance